# Changing product page "more information tab" view

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-page

Hi im new to the magento 2 development so i need some help here please.

I've managed to replace the more information(product.attributes) tab to the desired place. But i need to edit the view of this block but i cant find his location. Thanks in advance !
[image]

Answer (score 3):

the **"More information"** is displaying from this file

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

Then override this file in your theme folder and In

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

from this **xml** file below code is

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

is the reference for More information tab.You can move it and change as per your requirements and Don't change files in Vendor please override it in your Theme directory..

Comment: Is it possible to change this title as per product category?

Comment: @RonakParmar no you cannot add category title

Answer (score 0):

For those just looking for the required XML to change the text:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
    <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My string</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.copy i18n file and place it in ur folder.
2. In default.phtml for that span class change it as  echo __($label);
3. go to i18n->en.US.csv  folder and change as shown below.
4. "Details", "text u need to replace"
   "More Information", "text u need to replace"
5. reload cache and check browser.